# insufficient memory when rendering a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, graphics

I got an exception when launching a WPF application. Is this an issue with the Graphics card. the system only has 2GB of memory and a GMA 8150 graphics chipset.

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.    
at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.CompositionNode.SetGuidelineCollection(ResourceHandle hCompositionNode, DoubleCollection guidelinesX, DoubleCollection guidelinesY, Channel channel)    
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateGuidelines(Channel channel, ResourceHandle handle, VisualProxyFlags flags, Boolean isOnChannel)    
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)    
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)    
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
```

Comment: Read the following link. I think your application have some memory leaks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326904/finding-the-true-memory-footprint-of-a-windows-application/5407911#5407911

Comment: I found a knowledge base article that is related https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494124/